# Git commit history problem with Maven multi module project and Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, multi-module

**Description:**

We have a multi-module maven project and we use Jenkins as CI tool. My main goal was to detect which modules have been affected with last commit and build only those modules (and their dependents). I've done several searches over SO and blogposts and decided to use this way:

- clone certain branch into Jenkins
- git rev-list --parents -n 1 `<branch-name>`  (to get hashes of current commit and one commit before last. It gives me 2 outputs hash1 and hash2)
- git diff --name-status `<hash1>` `<hash2>` (to get differences between last two commit)

Output after this line is:

```
   M       moduleA/src/main/java/path/to/changed/files 
   M       moduleB/src/main/java/path/to/changed/files
```

- So we wrote a bash script to take only "moduleA, moduleB" string from above output and put it into:

`mvn install -amd -pl ${changed_module_names}`

Everything works as expected. But there is another problem.

**Problem:**

Lets say I've done some changes to code in my local machine and I know that there is also some changes in remote repository. So I use these commands to push to remote:

- git pull
- git add/commit
- git push origin `<branch>`

After these commands I can see one (!) commit history in the remote repository and it's okay:
[image]

But in second case, let's say I don't know about changes in remote repository. So I use:

- git add/commit
- git push origin `<branch>`
- it gives error and I need to pull
- git pull
- git push origin `<branch>`

After these steps I see two commits history in remote repository: ("test" is my actual commit)
[image]

So it brings about conflict with our Jenkins script:

`` git rev-list --parents -n 1 `<branch-name>` ``

Because in this case, it outputs 3 hashes while I expect 2 outputs.

How can I handle this situation? It's possible that someone can simply forget to git pull before git push and it'll break our pipeline.

Please let me know if you want more description

Comment: How many modules do you have ? How long does the build take? How long do the tests take? Do you use `mvn -T 4 package` already? Some kind of PoC https://github.com/khmarbaise/incremental-module-builder

Comment: It's not much time, something around 5 minutes for all. But why to rebuild and redeploy the modules that not changed?

Comment: Ok 5 Minutes ..have you tried to use `mvn -T 4..` already? I'm not sure if it's really worth the effort...

Comment: incremental-module-builder is on my mind. I'll try if I can't find a solution for current situation

Comment: No I didn't try. My consideration is not about build time

Comment: Then the question: What is really the problem?

Comment: The problem is I don't think it's good practice to rebuild/redeploy unchanged modules, isn't it?

Comment: Have you ever checked the exact output during the build in particular if you use `mvn package` or `mvn verify` instead of  `mvn clean install`? The difference between build time etc. ? And yes of course, but the solution should not being done outside Maven it should be done inside of Maven....